# How can I iterate through an arraylist to find a specific item in Java?

Tags: java

Say I'm creating some sort of quiz application, and I need to look through an arraylist of Answer objects for the user's chosen input, how would I go about it?

My ArrayList is this:

```
    ArrayList<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<Answer>();
    answers.add(new Answer(1, "A singer", true, 1));
    answers.add(new Answer(1, "A chef", false, 2));
    answers.add(new Answer(1, "A banana", false, 3));
    answers.add(new Answer(1, "A pineapple", false, 4));
```

The answer class has an int ID (to group them with questions), a String answer, a boolean isCorrect, and an int number, which is what the user chooses from when looking at the answers.

I just need to be able to say if the corresponding answer isCorrect or not

Thanks!

Comment: `for (Answer a : answers) { ... }`.

Comment: This question is neither unclear nor too broad. This is a typical case of SO users voting down or voting to close a question because they don't like that someone isn't as experienced a programmer as they are.

Comment: @david completely with you on that,  some of the down voting is completely ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have `question` and `choice` which are `1` and `3` and represent the current question and the answer the user chose. You can do something like this:

```
for (Answer answer : answers) {
    if (question == answer.getQuestion() && choice == answer.getChoice()) {
        return answer.isCorrect();
    }
}
throw new IllegalStateException("Choice not found???");
```

But it might be better to put the list of choices for each question into a map:

```
Map<Integer, List<Answer>> answers = new HashMap<>();
answers.put(1, List.of(
    new Answer(1, "A singer", true, 1),
    new Answer(1, "A chef", false, 2),
    new Answer(1, "A banana", false, 3),
    new Answer(1, "A pineapple", false, 4)));
```

And then you can pull out just the list of answers for the question you're interested in at a given point:

```
List<Answer> relevantAnswers = answers.get(question);
```

And then loop over just the ones that matter for the current question.

Comment: Managed to get it working, might explore that map option in the future though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
List<String[]> arrayList = new List<String[]>();
private String[] test1= {"123", "ABC", "USA"};
private String[] test2= {"", "BGD", "UK"};
arrayList.add(test1);
arrayList.add(test2);

for (String[] arr : arrayList)
{
string ID= arr[0]; 
string name= arr[1]; 
string address= arr[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for each loop

```
for(Answer a: answers) {
 int qid= a.getID();
 String ans = a.getAns();
 boolean res = a.getRes();
 int ansid= a.getAnsID();

 //compare result with this and print what you want
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Streams` from Java 8 or later

```
 int currentQuestion = 1;
 answers.stream().filter((a) -> (a.id == currentQuestion) && a.isCorrect)).findFirst().get();
```

Comment: This doesn't show how you would select the chosen option for the current question, it only always gets the first right answer to the very first question.

Comment: @DavidConrad Ok, Edited the answer